# How to resolve this 'code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve' & 'peer dependency' errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js, mantine

I want to have a website to give distance training, so I'm considering that and for quite a few days I've had this error, I searched a lot on several forums, but the solutions are not adapted to my reality. I just asked you to help me to have the site live on Vercel.

First, I would like to thank you for each response.

[image]

```
code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @mantine/rte@5.10.5 npm ERR! Found: @mantine/core@6.0.21 npm ERR! node_modules/@mantine/core
npm ERR!
@mantine/core@"^6.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer @mantine/core@"5.10.5" from @mantine/rte@5.10.5 npm ERR! node_modules/@mantine/Ite
nom ERR!
@mantine/rte@"^5.10.5" from the root project
npm ERR! npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @mantine/core@5.10.5
npm ERR!
node_modules/@mantine/core
npm ERR!
peer @mantine/core@"5.10.5" from @mantine/rte@5.10.5
npm ERR!
node_modules/@mantine/rte
npm ERR!
@mantine/rte@"^5.10.5" from the root project
```

Locally everything works very well, but I always got this message during deployment on Vercel, look at my package.json file.

```
    {
  "name": "elearniv",
  "version": "1.4.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "model:generate": "env-cmd sequelize-cli model:generate",
    "seed:generate": "env-cmd sequelize-cli seed:generate",
    "seed": "env-cmd sequelize-cli db:seed:all",
    "migrate": "env-cmd sequelize-cli db:migrate",
    "migrate:rollback": "env-cmd sequelize-cli db:migrate:undo",
    "migrate:rollback:all": "env-cmd sequelize-cli db:migrate:undo:all"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@etchteam/next-pagination": "^3.5.4",
    "@mantine/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@mantine/hooks": "^6.0.0",
    "@mantine/rte": "^5.10.5",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "framer-motion": "^7.3.4",
    "fslightbox-react": "^1.6.2-2",
    "html-to-image": "^1.10.8",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "next": "^14.1.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.7",
    "nookies": "^2.5.2",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-accessible-accordion": "^5.0.0",
    "react-confirm-alert": "^3.0.6",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.3.0",
    "react-jutsu": "^3.0.3",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^3.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-sticky-box": "^1.0.2",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "react-tabs": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "sass": "^1.54.0",
    "save": "^2.9.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.21.3",
    "stripe": "^10.2.0",
    "swiper": "^9.1.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "uuid-validate": "^0.0.3"
  }
  
}
```

I've had this error for 4 days, I've been doing research so far I can't find a solution.

Comment: at a guess it's because you want `@mantine/rte` version 5.10.5 and `@mantine/core` version 6.0.0 - you could try `--legacy-peer-deps` or changing `@mantine/rte` to `^6.0.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

If you create a project in a separate folder with `npm init`, run `npm i @mantine/rte@5.10.5`
and open your `package-lock.json`, you would see in its `peerDependencies` the following

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "@mantine/core": "5.10.5",
  "@mantine/hooks": "5.10.5",
  "react": ">=16.8.0",
  "react-dom": ">=16.8.0"
}
```

It means that for `@mantine/rte@5.10.5` to work, your project needs `@mantine/core@5.10.5` and currently you have `@mantine/core@6.0.0`. This is the problem.

You have the same issue between `react`, where you have version `18` and `react-jutsu` expects for versions `15.0.0`, `16.0.0` or `17.0.0`.

## Solution

You need to uninstall all these conflicting libraries and re-install them accordingly:

```
npm un @mantine/core @mantine/rte @mantine/hooks react-jutsu
```

Then install `@mantine` version `5.10.5`:

```
npm i @mantine/core@5.10.5 @mantine/rte@5.10.5 @mantine/hooks@5.10.5
```

Same thing, to be able to install `react-jutsu`, you need to downgrade `react` and `react-dom` to 17 or something. I would search for an equivalent library that supports React 18, or file an issue on their GitHub, instead of downgrading React, since you are using Next.js 14.